# How do you get a reference or instance of the Activity that launched the IME?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on a customized IME loosely based on the Android API Demo of SoftKeyboard. I need to get a reference or an instance of the Activity that launched my IME. For example, when my IME is launched by clicking on an input field (let's say an EditText widget in New Contacts Activity of Contacts application), my IME would be able to get a reference to the New Contacts Activity. Is this possible? If so, can someone direct me to some APIs I could use ?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get a reference or an instance of the Activity that launched my IME.

That is not possible. Most likely, you are in a completely separate process from the application that has the activity.